# Vector-matrix differentiation and vectorisation

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule, neural-networks, kronecker-product, vectorization

In recurrent neural network backpropagation (BPTT), we have the equations:
\begin{align}
e_t &= E^T x_t \\
a_t &= W_{hx}^T e_t+ W_{hh}^T h_{t-1}\\
h_t &= \text{tanh}(a_t) \\
s_t &= W_{yh}^T h_t \\
\hat{y}_t &= \text{softmax}(s_t)  \\
L_t &= \text{CE}(\hat{y}_t, y_t)
\end{align}
where $e_t$ has shape $(n_i, 1)$, $a_t, h_t$ have shape $(n_h,1)$, $s_t, \hat{y}_t$ have shape $(K,1)$. The matrices $W_{hx}, W_{hh}, W_{yh}$ have respective shapes $(n_i, n_h), (n_h, n_h), (n_h, K)$. $L_t$ is a scalar from the cross entropy loss function. All the $t$ represent a time step.

I would like to express the loss gradient with respect to the weight matrix transpose $W_{hx}^T$ at the first step. That is:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial W_{hx}^T} &= \frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial W_{hx}^T} \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial h_1} 
\end{align}
In particular $\frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial W_{hx}^T}$ requires a vectorisation for the matrix on the denominator. $W_{hx}^T$ has shape $(n_h, n_i)$, then $\text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)$ has shape $(n_hn_i, 1)$.

I am having trouble with:

1. expressing $\frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$.
2. and expressing $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial W_{hx}^T}$ from $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$, that is de-vectorisation operation.

My attempt so far:

1. $\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$.
   Let $f = W_{hx}^T e_1 = I_{n_h} W_{hx}^T e_1$, then $f$ also has shape $(n_h,1)$.
   \begin{align}
   df &= I_{n_h} d\text{vec}(W_{hx}^T) e_1 \\
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)^T} &= e_1^T \otimes I_{n_h} \\
   &= \frac{\partial a_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)^T} 
   \end{align}

Then
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)} &= \frac{\partial a_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}   \frac{\partial h_1}{\partial a_1} \\
&= (e_1^T \otimes I_{n_h})^T \text{ diag}(1- h_1^2) \\
&= (e_1 \otimes I_{n_h}) \text{ diag}(1- h_1^2)
\end{align}
this has shape $(n_in_h, n_h)$.

2. $\frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$ seems to have the same result and shape as $\frac{\partial h_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)} $. Can anyone confirm if I am right here?
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}&= \frac{\partial a_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)} \frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial a_1} \\
   &= (e_1 \otimes I_{n_h}) \text{ diag}(1- h_1^2)
   \end{align}
3. Finally the first-step (vectorised) loss gradient:
   \begin{align}
   \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)} &= \frac{\partial h_1^T}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)} \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial h_1} \\
   &= (e_1 \otimes I_{n_h}) \text{ diag}(1- h_1^2) \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial h_1}
   \end{align}
   where $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial h_1}$ has shape $(n_h, 1)$.

So $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$ has shape $(n_in_h, 1)$. But how to express $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial W_{hx}^T}$?

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial W_{hx}^T} &= \text{ diag}(1- h_1^2) \frac{\partial L_1}{\partial h_1} e_1^T
\end{align}
will have the right shape $(n_h, n_i)$. But how to proceed from the result of $\frac{\partial L_1}{\partial \text{vec}(W_{hx}^T)}$ to this result, if it is correct?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

For anyone who's interested with BPTT gradients, I will state the result for $\frac{\partial L_2}{\partial W_{hx}}$ with @greg 's method.

In particular, $a_2 = W_{hx}^T e_2 + W_{hh}^T h_1$ where $h_1$ depends on $W_{hx}$. Therefore $d a_2 = d w_{hx}^T e_2 + W_{hh}^T dh_1$.

This requires an additional identity of Frobenius product: $(A+C):(B+D) = A:B+A:D+C:B+C:D$. Starting from the loss $L_2$ and working backwards, this identity will be involved when we have $\cdots :da_2$.

The final result:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L_2}{\partial W_{hx}} &= (e_2 \hat{y}_2^T - e_2 y_2^T) W_{yh}^T (I_{n_h} - H_2^2) + (e_1 \hat{y}_2^T - e_1 y_2^T) W_{yh}^T (I_{n_h} - H_2^2) W_{hh}^T (I_{n_h} - H_1^2)
\end{align}
with shape $(n_i, n_h)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}\def\l{{\cal L}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\s#1{\operatorname{softmax}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$For ease of typing, drop the hats and subscripts,
and give each variable a unique name, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
a &= W^Te + U^Th &\qiq da = dW^Te \\
h &= \tanh(a) \\
H &= \Diag{h} &\qiq dh = \LR{I-H^2}da \\
s &= V^Th &\qiq ds = V^Tdh = V^T\LR{I-H^2}da \\
z &= \s{s} \\
Z &= \Diag{z} &\qiq dz = \LR{Z-zz^T}ds \\
}$$
Then starting with the loss function, calculate its
differential and back-substitute
$$\eqalign{
\l &= -y : \log(z) \\
d\l
 &= -y : Z^{-1}dz \\
 &= -Z^{-1}y : \c{dz} \\
 &= -Z^{-1}y : \c{\LR{Z-zz^T}ds} \\
 &= \LR{zz^T-Z}Z^{-1}y : ds \\
 &= \LR{z\o^T-I}y : ds \\
 &= \LR{z-y} : \c{ds} \\
 &= \LR{z-y} : \c{V^T\LR{I-H^2}da} \\
 &= \LR{I-H^2}V\LR{z-y} : \c{da} \\
 &= \LR{I-H^2}V\LR{z-y} : \CLR{dW^Te} \\
 &= \LR{z-y}^TV^T\LR{I-H^2} : \CLR{e^TdW} \\
 &= \LR{ez^T-ey^T}\LR{V^T-V^TH^2} : dW \\
\grad{\l}{W}
 &= \LR{ez^T-ey^T}\LR{V^T-V^TH^2} \\
\\
}$$
So you can do the entire calculation using differentials *without* resorting vectorization or awkward higher-order tensors. However, this method almost necessitates the use the Frobenius product,
which is a really concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
The properties of the underlying trace function (or the double summation) allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in many different but equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \\&= B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$